# my first run at databases and sqlite3 using python

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to put together a code that takes over 10000 CSV files to create one database.
The CSV files have the same amount of columns but varying lengths of rows.

Please note that my folder with all csv files will have various csv file names, therefore if I am to put together code to grab it, it needs to be open to grabbing ANY csv in this path location.

Question: how can I build my first database with the above prerequisites? Below you will find a sample of the data found in the csv

```
import glob
import os
import sqlite3
import csv
```

Create my database, and connect to it (this is all I have)

```
sqlite_file = '/Users/USERSNAME/Desktop/my_db.sqlite'
conn = sqlite3.connect(sqlite_file)
cur = conn.cursor()
```

Sample data from one of the csv

```
ad1988g7100c    1/25/1988   0.63    0.63    0.63    0.63    0   0
```

Comment: ...do you have a question?

Comment: please provide a row from one of your csv files

Comment: apologies - I have edited the original post. ty

Comment: Do you have a question that's not basically a request for a tutorial? Please see [ask] and consider taking the [tour].

Comment: The SQLite3 shell includes an `.import` command for creating a table from a CSV file.

Comment: if anyone is able to find a previously asked question with a solution, that is similar to what I am trying to accomplish, I would greatly appreciate it. I have not found one yet.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this can still help you, unless you've managed it in which case congratulations :) I can tell you how I did it when I started?

I read through my files with a quick python script and created a variable for each entry per row in my csv, I had read them in as lines but if you're using a csv reader they're likely in cells so you won't have to do that step.  Each line had two entries which I called 'A' and 'B'. I then put them together in a variable with the following syntax:

```
total = [(A, B)]
```

and used the following code to insert them into the database (my_db):

```
c.executemany("INSERT INTO my_db VALUES (?,?)", total)
```

The variable to be inserted took me a while to understand! Some of the documentation was difficult for me to read/understand as this is not my field so this took some trial and error. Hopefully it can help you.